# Build.xml in jenkins able to compile but not executing in Mac OSX

Tags: automated-testing, jenkins

I'm trying to execute build.xml am able to compile but not executing in MACOSX but it runs in Windows.
Here is my code and output

```
<project name="StrapUi" basedir=".">
    <!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
    <!-- set global properties for build -->
    <property name="basedir" value="." />
    <property name="lib" value="${basedir}/lib" />
    <property name="src" value="${basedir}/src" />
    <property name="bin" value="${basedir}/bin" />
    <property name="report-dir" value="${basedir}/Test-Report" />
    <property name="testng-report-dir" value="${report-dir}/TestNGreport" />

    <!-- ====== Set the classpath ====  -->
    <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="${bin}" />
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Delete directories  -->
    <target name="delete-dir">
        <delete dir="${bin}" />
        <delete dir="${report-dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Creating directories -->
    <target name="create" depends="delete-dir">
        <mkdir dir="${bin}" />
        <mkdir dir="${report-dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${bin} -->
    <target name="compile" depends="create">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" includeAntRuntime="No" destdir="${bin}" />
        <echo> /* Compiled Directory Classes */ </echo>
    </target>

    <!-- Runs the file and generates Reportng report for TestNG-->
    <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" classpathref="classpath" />

    <target name="testng-execution" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${testng-report-dir}" />
        <testng outputdir="${testng-report-dir}" classpathref="classpath" useDefaultListeners="true">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
        </testng>
    </target>
</project>
```

Output:

```
delete-dir:
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Github/StrapUi/bin
   [delete] Deleting directory /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Github/StrapUi/Test-Report

create:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Github/StrapUi/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Github/StrapUi/Test-Report

compile:
    [javac] Compiling 55 source files to /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Github/StrapUi/bin
     [echo]  /* Compiled Directory Classes */ 

testng-execution:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Github/StrapUi/Test-Report/TestNGreport
   [testng] [TestNG] Running:
   [testng]   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Github/StrapUi/testng.xml
   [testng] 
   [testng] Oct 28, 2016 2:38:22 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
   [testng] INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
   [testng] _RegisterApplication(), FAILED TO establish the default connection to the WindowServer, _CGSDefaultConnection() is NULL.
   [testng] 2016-10-28 14:38:24.756 firefox-bin[1312:72325] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
   [testng] 2016-10-28 14:38:24.759 firefox-bin[1312:72325] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
   [testng] 2016-10-28 14:38:24.760 firefox-bin[1312:72325] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
   [testng] 2016-10-28 14:38:24.767 firefox-bin[1312:72325] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
   [testng] 1477645705092   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53573...........
```

Here the pointer rotates but not getting output.

Comment: sindhu, is this your other account? Do you want the two merged in together? https://sqa.stackexchange.com/users/21918/sindhu

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Jenkins is unable to access WindowServer

Type this in terminal:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
sudo mv /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Then restart your machine

Now Jenkins will run as agent and can access WindowServer.  Also seems like you don't have Jenkins configured to run on machine startup, so you may run

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Comment: Hey bountyhunter your answer worked for me thank you so so so much i have been struggled for this since 2 days.. thanks a lot cheers:)

Comment: Glad this worked for you. Could you please mark the answer as accepted, thanks